# How do i get colors with GetSysColorBrush?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm having some problems with my c++ project.

I'm using windows.h and i don't know how to get colors.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow ! Can you show us what you have done so far ? Have you made some researches ? Also check [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ;)

Comment: Click https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsyscolorbrush and then click https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsyscolor

Answer (score 1):

If you want the color that corresponds to the brush returned by GetSysColorBrush use the GetSysColor function instead. The two functions take the same argument set, just one returns an HBRUSH while the other returns a COLORREF value.

If that is not what you are after you are going to have to provide much more detail.